# What does it mean 'to hit a switch on someone '?

Tags: meaning, slang

> My woman claiming that I switched on her
>   Only 'cause I hit a switch on her
>
> She wasn't really good at keeping up

I don't understand what it means to hit a switch on her, if I get the previous line right that he beat her up while they were in a bed, it have to be associated with sexual violence...Help me please

Upd: I have found the same phrase by Rihanna

Hit a switch on a fake nigga

Answer (score 1):

The lyrics aren't really grammatical, but basically it means:

> My woman claiming that I switched on her

"Switch" in this sense means that she thinks he has suddenly changed the way he is treating her.

> Only because I hit a switch on her

"Hit a switch" is hip-hop slang for having a lot of crazy sex.

Comment: so he is saying he had enough a lot of crazy sex with her?

Comment: Yeah, my own interpretation would be that she thinks he's a completely different person ("switched on her") because of the awesome sex he's been having with her.

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hitting%20the%20switches

Here, "hitting the switch" is turning on the energy switch for 2Pac's "hydraulics," meaning his penis is like an engine piston that never stops.

Answer (score 1):

In my interpretation

- "switch on somebody" means to cheat (although Ringo's answer is new to me and I cannot ignore that)
- "hit a switch" might mean

  - to trigger someone, trip someone up - to cause someone to become suspicious, agitated, to drive somebody mad
  - to push someone's buttons, to push someone - to play tricks on someone, make them do something they didn't want to do
  - to push someone's buttons, to make somebody click - to work someone to good effect

Again, Ringo's idea is considerable. I haven't heard this term before either. I doubt it's "hip hop" lingo though. If anything, to push someone's neuralgic points. That doesn't mean crazy sex per-se.

The truth is, rhymes may be made up and forced and do not always have to be completely meaningful, though, ambiguity can be intended or at least acceptable, e.g. to reach a broader group of listeners.

Answer (score 1):

"Hit a switch" ultimately comes from a lowrider/low low/scraper with hydraulics installed. You hit the switch and it gets poppin. Gets bouncing. Hit a switch on someone is to get poppin on them. Often sexually. 6lack says she's claiming that he switched on her because it's pretty common for your partner to think you're having sex someone else if all of a sudden you're having sex like a pornstar or bust a new move. Hence him saying she couldn't keep up.

Obviously he knows best but that made perfect sense to me. He's from ATL though and I'm in Cali.